# Writing articles based on the "Least Publishable Unit"

Tags: research-process, writing

I have heard the term "Least Publishable Unit" used to describe the amount of scientific information that holds enough merit for a publication. From my understanding, there are two sides to publishing with this term in mind:

1) The positive aspect of this concept is the fact that the article remains focused on the research question and tends to be concise.

2) The downside, at least for me, is this notion of only obtaining enough data simply to produce publications.

Has anyone else heard of this term used when discussing publications? If so, is my interpretation of it correct?

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen the term used as a "positive" thing. Usually it is in the context of people trying to inflate their publication count.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought as well, but then when I had reviewers suggest I take out some material, which will become a later publication, I started thinking more about this term and wondered if it really does have this double meaning.

Comment: It should be "least publishable unit", not "lowest".

Comment: @David thank you!  Good point. Tell tale signs I have been staring at the screen for too long.

Comment: Another relevant keyword for this is *salami publication.*

Comment: I think all of your answers led me to this question: Can using the LPU/Salami publication approach ever be useful/beneficial to the scientific community?

Comment: @IHeartBeats Please post a new question as, well, a new question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To summarise what's in some of the comments... this term is usually used in a cynical, sardonic or derogatory fashion, to describe the practise of "salami-slicing" research into lots of papers, each of which has the minimum amount of content necessary to get published. The aim of this approach is to maximise the number of publications that can be obtained from a given piece of research.

Some believe that this approach is encouraged by hiring practises in universities that depend upon the number of publications a researcher has, rather than their quality.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have only heard it used jokingly thus I wasn't sure what the actual implication of the term was.

Comment: US universities at least definitely incentivize this practice. In my field I frequently see these, really an idea/research/experiment/engineering feat which could have been published in 2-3 papers is published in 5-10. And guess who the worst offenders are? The top people in the field. Then people in the COI/RCR dept. have the audacity to tell us junior scientists not to engage in this behavior. I agree it is wrong, but when tenure decisions and post-doc success are heavily tied to it, you aren't going to get a different outcome...